# How to implement z index in java script high chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Iam trying to implement a graph using js and php.

I have created the graph. Now it shows the y axis value and x axis value when the user click on the graph points. I want to show another value (other than x and y ) when the user click on the graph points. I have returned all these x, y, and the z value from the ajax file. But can't implement the z index . Plz help me.

```
$("document").ready(function(event){
    var pickerOpts = {
            dateFormat:"d/m/yy"

            };

    $('.date').datepicker(pickerOpts);
    function loadGraph(d1,d2){


    $.ajax({

            dataType:'json',
            type:'POST',
            url:'../ajaxtaskAnalytics',
            data:{
                date1:d1,
                date2:d2
            },
            success:function(result){


            $.parseJSON(result);

            var gval=[];
            for(var i=0;i<result['tasks'].length;i++){

                gval.push([

                            Date.parse(result['tasks'][i].dt+' UTC')
                            , 
                            result['tasks'][i].number,
                            result['tasks'][i].usercount
                        ]);

            } 

            var options = {

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Task Analytics'
                },

                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Machbee'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickInterval: 1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    labels: {
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 3,
                        y: -3 
                    }
                },

                yAxis: [{ // left y axis
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    labels: {
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 3,
                        y: 16,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                        }
                    },
                    showFirstLabel: false
                }, { // right y axis
                    linkedTo: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    opposite: true,
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    labels: {
                        align: 'right',
                        x: -3,
                        y: 16,
                        formatter: function() {

                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                        }
                    },
                    showFirstLabel: false
                }],

                legend: {
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 20,
                    floating: true,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },

                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    crosshairs: true
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function() {

                                    hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                        pageOrigin: {
                                            x: this.pageX, 
                                            y: this.pageY
                                        },
                                        headingText:  Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y %b %e', this.x),
                                        maincontentText: ' Total Tasks :'+this.y ,
                                        width: 200
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        marker: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Task Info',
                    lineWidth: 4,
                    marker: {
                        radius: 4
                    }
                }]
            };
            options.series[0].data = gval;
            //options.series[1].data = gval;

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


            $("#analyticsTaskCount").html("No Of Tasks in this WorkSpace is"+result['total']);          


            $("#analyticsUser").html("");
            for(var k=0;k<result['users'].length;k++){

                $("#analyticsUser").append("<br>"+result['users'][k].name+"="+result['users'][k].taskcount);

            } 

            }
            });
            }
            loadGraph($("#sdate").val(),$("#ddate").val()); 


            var okay=true;

            $("#sdate").live('click',function(){

                    $("#err_startdate").html("");               

            });

            $("#ddate").live('click',function(){

                if($("#sdate").val().length<8){

                    $("#err_startdate").html("Please select the first date");
                    okay= false;
                }


            });
            $("#ddate").live('blur',function(){
                $("#err_enddate").html("");
                if($("#sdate").val().length<8){

                    $("#err_startdate").html("Please select the first date");
                    okay=false;
                }
                if($("#ddate").val().length<8){

                    $("#err_enddate").html("Please select the second date");
                    okay=false;
                }

            });
            $("#ddate").live('change',function(){
                loadGraph($("#sdate").val(),$("#ddate").val());             
            });

});
```

=================================== OUT PUT FROM AJAX FILE =======

```
(
[tasks] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [added_on] => 1322629212
                [dt] => 2011/11/30
                [number] => 3
                [usercount] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [added_on] => 1323071708
                [dt] => 2011/12/05
                [number] => 2
                [usercount] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [added_on] => 1323424536
                [dt] => 2011/12/09
                [number] => 1
                [usercount] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [added_on] => 1323754243
                [dt] => 2011/12/13
                [number] => 2
                [usercount] => 1
            )

    )

[users] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => God
                [taskcount] => 7
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Veela
                [taskcount] => 1
            )

    )

[total] => 8
```

)

Comment: show your markup and css

Comment: Please only include the bits of your javascript that are relevant to the problem, not the entire script.  Also, the relevant PHP and CSS would be useful to have as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the formatter property in the chart's tooltip option and you will need to have an array that contains the z value.  See the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hHjZb/5/